# How to merge two CSV files by Python based on the common information in both files?

Tags: python, csv, merge

Evans,
Great thanks. It is almost the expected result. Please kindly take a hand to modify as follows.
We need a little change. Please take a look at the image.
In the present result, each record in fileOne search the similar adv_id and user_id in the fileTwo and when find a record take it and stop. But possibility is that there may be several similar records in fileTwo. So, we need all the similar records from fileTwo. And all records of fileOne must be available at least once or several times in fileTwo. So, we should include all record of fileOne and all of their similar records from fileTwo.  I think a row by row search might be helpful. That is take adv_id and user_id of first of fileOne and search all records in fileTwo to find the similar record. Next use 2nd record of fileOne and search all record in fileTwo. And so on.

[Revised Image For Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv79G.png)

Comment: Hi there. This is a very good statement of what you need, but I don't see any evidence of you having tried something. Would you let us know what issues you encountered when you tried writing this, or if you have not done so yet, give it a go first, and then modify the question if necessary to explain what difficulties you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How two merge several .csv files horizontally with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986353/how-two-merge-several-csv-files-horizontally-with-python)

Comment: How does `conv_id` affect the merge?  When a matching entry is found in both files, which one needs to be kept?

Comment: The question as currently written makes no sense; it looks like the edit removed the original context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will create `result.csv` based on your original sample data (see past edits to question):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d_entries = defaultdict(list)

with open('fileTwo.csv', 'r') as f_fileTwo:
    csv_fileTwo = csv.reader(f_fileTwo)
    header_fileTwo = next(csv_fileTwo)
    for cols in csv_fileTwo:
        d_entries[(cols[0], cols[1])].append([cols[0], ''] + cols[1:])

with open('fileOne.csv', 'r') as f_fileOne, open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_result:
    csv_fileOne = csv.reader(f_fileOne)
    csv_result = csv.writer(f_result)
    header_fileOne = next(csv_fileOne)
    csv_result.writerow(header_fileOne)

    for cols in csv_fileOne:
        if (cols[0], cols[2]) in d_entries:
            csv_result.writerow(cols)
            csv_result.writerows(d_entries.pop((cols[0], cols[2])))
```

`result.csv` will then contain the following data when opened in Excel:

[image]

Tested in Python 3.4.3

To only match on the `adv_id` columns and to have all entries:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d_entries = defaultdict(list)

with open('fileTwo.csv', 'r') as f_fileTwo:
    csv_fileTwo = csv.reader(f_fileTwo)
    header_fileTwo = next(csv_fileTwo)
    for cols in csv_fileTwo:
        d_entries[cols[0]].append([cols[0], ''] + cols[1:])

with open('fileOne.csv', 'r') as f_fileOne, open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_result:
    csv_fileOne = csv.reader(f_fileOne)
    csv_result = csv.writer(f_result)
    header_fileOne = next(csv_fileOne)
    csv_result.writerow(header_fileOne)

    for cols in csv_fileOne:
        if cols[0] in d_entries:
            csv_result.writerows(d_entries.pop(cols[0]))
        csv_result.writerow(cols)
```

Comment: Hello Evans

Many thank

1. conv_id should not affect in the merging process now. It can be used for sorting later after merging. 

the all_cv file contains information of converted users, so cvflg = 1.
non_cv file contains information of the non converted users, so set cvflg = 0.
Keep all entries of the both files, and should not be overlapped. 

Found runtime error:
  File "join_cv_noncv.py", line 9, in <module>
    header_noncv = next(csv_noncv)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Pls look and revise accordingly.
Regards,
Tofa

Comment: I am guessing you are using Python 3, it was written for Python 2. It should now work in Python 3. Note, if the output is not as required, please edit the question to include example inputs for both files and expected output.

Comment: The current version is designed to work with Python 3 only.

Comment: As you have chosen not to use Python's CSV handling, you would need to do something like `df.to_csv('out.csv')` on your Pandas dataframe.

Comment: You should not post code into comments. There is nothing stopping you from editing your question to include this (there is an edit button). As I have already asked, it would also help to include sample input files and expected output.

Comment: Hello Evans,
I have added fileOne.csv, fileTwo.csv and expected result.csv as a image file. Please take a look  and give me your suggestion and advise.
Now it is very clear to understand what I want to do.
Thanks

Comment: Your screen shot was very helpful and explained what you were trying to achieve. I have updated my script to produce the correct output. Note, my solution does not use pandas.

Comment: Hello Evans,
Than oou very much.
It is almost what I want. I need a little change. Could you please take a look on my revised image and explanaiton at the top of the post.

Thank you very much for you kind consideraiton.

Comment: Hi Evans,
Any new idea based on the revised explanation?

Comment: My existing code will also work perfectly with your revised explanation? Have you tried it?  What is the problem? Just open `results.csv` in Excel. `fileOne` and `fileTwo` must be in CSV format (not Excel `.xlsx` format).

Comment: Hello Evans,
Thanks. It is almost working but need to arrange the data a little, because cvflg colum is displaced into two columns. I have revised the graph. Please take a look and if possible please reply me as soon possible. 
Could you please take a look on the picture.
I sincerely appriciate your help.

Comment: I can only assume your input file has additional columns that you have not shown. My result was correct based on your data. I afraid the question is no longer readable to anyone else. The solution should be accepted by clicking the tick, and you should start a new question. I would then be able to help better.

Comment: Hello Evans,
Thank you very much. I had a simple mistake in the file. Your program is now working exactly.
Thank you so much for your kind support.

Comment: I am glad you figured out what the problem was. I would appreciate it if you would accept the solution by clicking the tick by the answer.

Comment: Hello Evans,
I cannot find the "tick" to accepet the solution, please let me know where it is.
In addition, I like to use only adv_id in the condition for both files. So, when I use, if (cols[0] in d_entries: alignment of columns changed in the result file. Could you please give a suggestion how can I do this exactly.
Thank you,

Comment: I have added a possible solution to only use adv_id. The 'tick' (or check mark) is below the up down arrows to the left of my answer, it is coloured grey, and will turn green when you click it.

Comment: Hello Evans,
Thank you. I have confirmed the tick.
I have also revised “csv_result.writerows(d_entries.pop(cols[0]))”- line.
I also need a little more revision. Presently the program take a record from fileOne, it then search for the similar records in the fileTwo, and take one record from fileOne and all the similar records form fileTwo. But, similar records are also available in fileOne. So, I want to take all similar records from both fileOne and fileTwo.
Evans, is it possible that I get your more support by compensation? If you wish, I would be happy for that.

Comment: One last attempt. I have added a 2nd solution under the first. If this does not solve matters, I suggest you start a new question as it is getting quite confusing. I will then take a look at that. Don't post pictures though, post the actual data as text otherwise people will have to enter it manual and so not bother to answer or close your question until you have fixed it.

Comment: Evans, 
An argent matter. In am going to use all the code in the server where python version is 2.6.6. As a result I encounter an error “SyntaxError: invalid syntax' at the above program as the following line. I think this is due to the version problem. Could you please take a look. It is a little urgent.  

with open('all_cv_1000.csv', 'r') as f_fileOne, open('commonFromAccess.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_result: